# How to insert a space automatically after certain keywords in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, whitespace, jetbrains-ide

I want to insert a space automatically after certain keywords. For example when typing:

```
in<return_key> => int<no_space>
```

Then I have to **type a space** to name a variable like so:

```
int x = ...;
```

What I want IntelliJ to do is the following:

```
in<return_key> => int<space>
```

Now I do **not** need to type the space to name a variable because the IDE already inserted it automatically.

(This behavior is already enabled in **if, for, while ...**) I want to enable this behavior with **primitives**, **Object types**. How can I do it in IDEA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such setting currently, and automatic space insertion would probably be annoying if you want to type `int.class`, `OuterClass.InnerClass` or `Util.someMethod()`.